# Amount of data that can be passed in $state.go() angular js

Tags: angularjs

I am doing a `$http.post()` action from my Angular controller to the server and I  get the response as a JSON Object. I would like to pass that object in `$state.go()` to redirect to another page. Does `$state.go()` has any limitation regarding the amount of data that is kept in that object since that object will be appended to the url?

Comment: That duplicate link isn't a good answer for this.

Comment: The links which you have provided as answer didn't answer my question.Please check those links once.